# User Control with button and button events

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am currently working on my first User Control, and are now experiencing some minor problems.

The control is a custom `PictureBox` with a `Button` to clear the picture. I am overriding the `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` method and invalidating the control on `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` to draw new borders to the control based on mouse state.

This all work as it should. The problem occurs when I want to add a button in the upper right corner (relative to the PictureBox).

**1.**
The button will not have the correct location relative to the PictureBox. It is placed at the 0th Y-coordinate which is fine, but the X-coordinate is only at position 100, where it should be 160. I am using the `User Controls Width property` when placing the button, but it seems as it is getting a `default value` of 100 instead of the 160 that is assigned creating the PictureBox on the form.

```
CustomPictureBox cpic = new CustomPictureBox();
cpic.Location = new Point(20, 20);
cpic.Height = 80;
cpic.Width = 160;
this.Controls.Add(cpic);
```

And the button is added like this:

```
btnClear = new Button();
btnClear.Width = 20;
btnClear.Height = 20;
btnClear.Location = new Point(this.Width - btnClear.Width, 0);
btnClear.Text = "X";
this.Controls.Add(btnClear);
```

Where does this DefaultValue come from and how can it prevent the control from using it and instead following the width that is specified when initializing a new instance of the control?

**2.**
Another thing is that I can not get the events for the button to work. I have been googling a lot and tried everything that I can possibly think of, but the events are still not fireing :(

It must be possible to hook on to the buttons MouseClick, MouseEnter and MouseLeave events directly from the User Control?

If you want to see the complete code, you can find it here:
http://pastebin.com/vL14Q5CX

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The button is not aligning as expected because:

1. The button's location is being set in the constructor of the user control
2. The user control's width is then set in the form
3. The user control's Resize event is not being handled

In your user control wire up the Resize event and update the location of the button, i.e.:

```
private void CustomPictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnClear.Location = new Point(this.Width - btnClear.Width, 0);
}
```

The reason the button click events aren't working is because they only bubble up to the parent user control; they will not be received by the form that is hosting the control. You need to create a new custom event handler on your user control that you fire from within the button click event of your user control. You then handle that custom event handler on your form.

HTH

Comment: I know about the Anchor property, but unfortunately that is also not the problem.